# PHP Namespaces with Composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to move a couple of libraries to Composer/Packagist and am struggling with php namespace mapping.

- Classfiles are in a folder Csp under /src. They have a PHP namespace Csp.
- The `composer.json` generated by compose init contains (not sure if that is correct though)

```js
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Theking2\\Csp\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

- The package is registered on Packagist `https://packagist.org/packages/theking2/`
- In a test project I require the package
- In the `index.php` I have as per documentation

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

- and

```php
$csp = new Csp\Builder(true);
```

But I get a class not found error.

EDIT also with this in `composer.json`:

```js
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Csp\\": "src/Csp" }
    },
```

or this

```js
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Csp\\": "src/Csp" }
    },
```

same results. The files sit in the folder `src/Csp` directly under `vendor/Theking2/csp-builder` as `compose update` created it.

And just before anyone askes: Yes there is a `namespace Csp;` in every file.

Comment: 1) Is your namespace `\Theking2\Csp` (as you declare in Composer) or `\Csp` (as you mention in the question? 2) Read the error message, it says what class it's trying to load.

Comment: No it is not. But it how `composer init` generated it. I already tried by removing the prefix in composer.json which much the same results.

Comment: In the debuger I see ClassLoader\ClassLoader::loadClass that fineFile returs false.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Btw the PHP error is `Uncaught Error: Class "Csp\Builder"` so it does not show what file it is attempting to load.

Comment: see the `namespace` in these projects. Do they match what you set in `composer.json` map?

Comment: I think it isn't trying to load any file at all because that namespace is unknown in config. I didn't know Composer tries to guess autoload rules. It's not doing it correctly, so you'll have to edit the file manually.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that is a good question as I tend to mix case but yes, they all match up. files under `src/Csp`, in PHP `namespace Csp;`, in composer.json  `psr-0: { "Csp\\": "src/CSp" }`. run `composer dump-autoload` every time `composer.json` is changed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález What do you mean by _config_ ?

Comment: In `vendor\composer\autoload_static.php` I find  `        'Theking2\\Csp\\' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/theking2/csp-builder/src',
        ),` which seems odd.

Comment: I redid the `composer init` and wonder what to make of this line `Add PSR-4 autoload mapping? Maps namespace "Theking2\CspBuilder" to the entered relative path. [src/, n to skip]: ` I never told composer what PHP namespace to use. To this question is rathre confusing. I think there is going to be bug report to the composer team.  Or at least a RFD

Comment: Please clarify the usage of namespaces. If there is `namespace Csp;` in every file, why do you initially use `"Theking2\\Csp\\"` in your composer.json?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's what `composer init` came up with. I understand now why but wasn't very clear for me.

Comment: A request for documentation it is. My answer is the first draft.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to consider when using `composer init`. The first question (`<vendor><name>`) defines quite a lot and defaults to whatever user is logged on (?) and what folder she is working in. Of course this can be changed but it needs some thinking ahead. Therefor take this step by step.

### Setting up the package

#### What we want

Lets assume these prerequisites:

| entity | value |
| --- | --- |
| vendor | kingsoft |
| package under development | csp-builder |
| developer/logged on user | joking |
| github user developing | theking2 |
| Packagist name | kingsoft |
| PHP namespace | Kingsoft\Csp |
| source root | src/ |

Lets assume the package is not dependent on anything and has a MIT license, all of which are not relevant.

#### Let's compose!

Answer to the first question of `composer init` has to be changed
`kingsoft/csp-builder`. The answer to the 9th question (PSR-4 autoload mapping) can be answered yes but we have to change the effect of that answer  later on. After generating, observe the last couple of lines:

```
Generating autoload files
Generated autoload files
PSR-4 autoloading configured. Use "namespace Kingsoft\CspBuilder;" in src/
Include the Composer autoloader with: require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

#### Autoloader adjustment

A good guess for the namespace but we want to change it to `Kingsoft\Csp`. Do this in the generated `composer.json`

```js
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kingsoft\\Csp\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

This now will assume the source files in the folder `src/` and those directly within have a

```php
namespace Kingsoft\Csp;
```

close to the top. (Probably directly after a `<?php declare(strict_types=1);`.)

#### Commit and push

Now commit this and sync it with a repo on whatever git provider you use. Maybe before that tag it with:

```bash
git tag 1.0.0
```

#### Packagist

On Packagist set up a new package (`csp-builder`) under account `kingsoft` and add the relevant hooks to for instance GitHub after connecting the Packagist account with the GitHub account. (not sure how to this on other git hosters, leave a message in the comments).

Small changes (typos etc.) not involving code during the setup might need commits and retagging with

```bash
git tag 1.0.1 --force && git push -f --tags
```

Of course later on after code changes you might (must) add tags to newer versions.

That is most of the work. Now to ..

### Use the package

That is easy. Create a `composer.json` with this minimal content:

```js
{
    "require": {
        "kingsoft/csp-builder": "*"
    }
}
```

and type this in a terminal

```bash
composer update
```

and use whatever is contained in `Kingsoft\Csp`. Like

```php
$csp = new Kingsoft\Csp\Builder(true);
$csp-> setCspHeader();
```

Or shorten the names of imports a bit by importing the namespace: `use Kingsoft\Csp;` and leave out the vendor name on classnames etc. (but do include namespace `Csp\`!) like `new Csp\Builder(true);`.

I'm writing this quite elaborate answer for my own future reference.